# Pandas dataframe, match column against list of sub-strings, continuous rows, keep only sub-string

Tags: string, pandas, dataframe, intersection

In a Pandas dataframe, I want to match Col1 against a list of keywords as follow:

Keywords need to be different, located in the same column and on 3 continuous rows (keyword1 != keyword2 != keyword3 and they are located for example on rows x, x+1 and x+2)

I only want the keywords to be returned as results (in the example below " def" is being removed)

```
list_keywords = ['abc', 'ghi', 'jkl mnop','blabla']

Index  Col1

1     abc def
2     ghi
3     jkl mnop
4     qrstu
5     vw
```

```
>>>

1     abc
2     ghi
3     jkl mnop
```

Comment: `pat = '|'.join(list_keywords); df.Col1.str.extract(f'({pat})')`?

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this with `df.iterrows()`.

```
for _, row in df.iterrows():
  if row['col1'] in list_keywords:
    row['col1'] = row['col1']
  else:
    val = row['col1'].split()
    row['col1'] = ' '.join(str(i) for i in val if i in list_keywords)

df

    col1
0   abc
1   ghi
2   jkl mnop
3   
4
```

Comment: Sorry to ask a newbie question, but how can I apply this to my df? Do I need to turn this into a function?

Comment: You can use the code directly (not required to convert into function) assuming that your dataframe is named `df` or just use the name of your dataframe wherever I have used `df`. Let me know if this helps you!

Answer (score 0):

Based on @HTRS 's answer, here is what seems to be a partial answer to my question.
This piece of code filters column Brands against a list of keywords and filter out the parts of strings that differ from keywords.

```
import pandas as pd

list_filtered = []
list_keywords = ['abc', 'ghi', 'jkl mnop','blabla']

for _, row in df.iterrows():
  if row['Brand'] in list_keywords:
     row['Brand'] = row['Brand']
     list_filtered.append(row['Brand'])
  else:
    val = row['Brand'].split()
    row['Brand'] = ' '.join(str(i) for i in val if i in list_keywords)
    list_filtered.append(row['Brand'])

df['Filtered'] = list_filtered
print(df)
```

Comment: Can you please accept my answer if it solved your question? Thanks.